# i want to enter db data i.e subject name, teacher, room, in html table as i am making a time table. What approach will be the best in asp.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net

i want to enter db data i.e subject name, teacher, room, in html table as i am making a time table. What approach will be the best in asp.net?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately you question is quite unclear. Have you tried something yourself? Can you show any code? This would help a lot.

Comment: The best approach is to break the task down into smaller steps, and then research and solve each one separately. It's unclear what part of this might be giving you difficulty. If you're new to asp.net then make sure you have some general resources such as tutorials and textbooks, and the official documentation available so you can look things up and understand the basic concepts before you start. Your question is too vague for us to answer meaningfully, there could be many ways to solve it depending on the rest of your circumstances

Answer (score -1):

You can use Entity Framework for CRUD (Create, read, update and delete) operations. It will be easy for you.

you can visit  https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net for more information about Entity Framework.

Have a nice day.

Comment: I have a html table of time table which has days and time slots. I have a form which is taking input of subject and time slots(in bit) in saving in SQL . How can i view this SQL data in table .